# Validating file geodatabase information against spreadsheet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, data-validation

I have a spreadsheet from our master records office that contains thousands of entries for different types of facilities (building, signs, canopy, fences).

I need to validate that we have all of these features in our file geodatabase, but they are grouped by feature datasets and feature classes based on what they are (building feature class, fence feature class, sign feature class).

There would be at least one, possibly two, unique fields that can be matched for every single facility in both areas.

I would like to know what the most efficient method would be for validating the data we have in our GIS with our master spreadsheet.

The options that seem available to me are to either start with the master spreadsheet at building #001, find which feature class it belongs to, open the attribute table and find the entry, or tackle it by feature class (all buildings first, then signs, etc). I have any tools available within ArcGIS available and some python knowledge (but not enough!).

Comment: Are you opposed to .net arc object development?

Comment: @Tobel a screenshot of the spreadsheet and geodatabase structure would be helpful.

Comment: @ian Unfortunately, the information can't be shown here. I know it's a bit challenging to describe this without pictures, a bit frustrating to me too.

Comment: @Chris I know nothing about .net, but if its something I can pick apart and make work I would be willing to try it.